# Complex conjugate of polar form of $z \in \mathbb C$

Tags: complex-numbers

Express in regular form the conjugates of $z \in c$ that satisfy $z^2 + 4i = 0$

Let $$ z=re^{i\theta} $$
Thus
$z^2 = -4i =  4e^{i\frac{3\pi}2} $

$r^2=4, r=2$

$\theta_1  = \frac{3\pi}4, \theta_2  = \frac{7\pi}4 $

Thus, $z_1 =2e^{i\frac{3\pi}4}, z_2 =2e^{i\frac{7\pi}4} $

Here comes the part I don't get it. How did they get the **rectangular** from the  **exponential or polar form**?

$z_1 = -\sqrt2 +\sqrt2i, z_2 = \sqrt2 -\sqrt2i  $

$\bar{z_1} = -\sqrt2 -\sqrt2i, \bar{z_2} =\sqrt2 +\sqrt2i  $

Comment: In mathematics it is customary to write $\;i=\sqrt{-1}\;$ , not $\;j\;$

Comment: Engineers always write $j=\sqrt{-1}$, while they are used to write $i$ for the current.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The complex conjugate of the polar form of a complex number is given by $$\overline{re^{i\theta}}=re^{-i\theta}.$$

To see why, use [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula):
\begin{align}
\overline{r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)}&=\overline{r}\ \overline{(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)}\\
&=r\,(\cos\theta-i\sin\theta)\\
&=r\,(\cos(-\theta)+i\sin(-\theta))\quad\text{[since cosine is even and sine is odd]}\\
&=r\,e^{-i\theta}.
\end{align}

So you can find the conjugates of your $z$ without converting first to rectangular form.

Of course, if you do want to convert from polar to rectangular form, just use Euler's formula employed above:

$$z=re^{i\theta}=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$$

which can be converted to rectangular form $z=a+bi$ via $$a=r\cos\theta,\quad b=r\sin\theta,$$ which in your case leads to $a=2\cos(3\pi/4)=-\sqrt 2$ and $b=2\sin(3\pi/4)=\sqrt 2$. So $$z=2e^{i{3\pi\over 4}}=-\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt{2}\implies \overline{z}=2e^{-i{3\pi\over 4}}=-\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{2}.$$ You can do the other one.

Comment: ${re^{i\theta}=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)}$ was exponational to polar form. How did we get about $z_1 = -\sqrt2 +\sqrt2i, z_2 = \sqrt2 -\sqrt2i  $

Comment: Edited to include that explanation too.